# Join two table with everything

Tags: mysql

I have to tables that I want to get all the results of both connect by a common cell. The problems is the second table only has some of records of the first table.

```
Table 1 forms
form_id, description, image,dept

Table 2 records
record_id, form_id, comments, added_date, done_date
```

If do a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM form
JOIN records ON record.form_id = form.form_id
```

I do not get all of the forms because there is no record for that form. Is there away to do something like this? I would create a blank record for each form on in the records table, but I could not figure that out either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use left join for these cases

```
SELECT * FROM form
LEFT JOIN records ON record.form_id = form.form_id
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect application for a LEFT OUTER JOIN.
Example:

```
SELECT f.*, r.*
FROM   form f
       LEFT JOIN records r
       ON r.form_id = f.form_id
ORDER BY f.description, r.added_date;
```

Comment: THis will raise an error `column form_id is ambiguous`. You have to specify the columns with an alias `SELECT f.form_id, f.description, f.image, f.dept, r.record_id, r.form_id as record_form_id, r.comments, r.added_date, r.done_date FROM ...` or don't even query r.form_id to reduce the data transfered over the wire. Anyway, `LEFT JOIN` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please check which one u need -- 
`LEFT OUTER JOIN` : 
Will include all records from Table Mentioned in Left Side and Matched Records from Right Side table, unmached record will be null

Ex :

```
SELECT * 
FROM forms
LEFT JOIN records ON  forms.form_id = record.form_id
```

`FULL OUTER JOIN`:
Will include all data from both table and unmatched will be null

Ex :

```
SELECT * 
FROM forms
FULL OUTER JOIN records ON  forms.form_id = record.form_id
```